# How do I use other packages while writing my own package

Tags: ros2, lidar, packages

Im just starting out with ros2, and I have been trying to do something that I thought would be very common.
I want to use the functions available inside some other package in my own node. The package in questions is ld08_driver lds-02 lidar driver [github link](https://github.com/ROBOTIS-GIT/ld08_driver/tree/ros2-devel) and I see that inside the /include/lipkg.h file, I see that there are functions like GetSpeed, GetTimestamp and so on.
What I’m asking is, is it not possible to do something like how rclpy is imported and used, “Import ld08_driver” and just use those functions and not use the pre-created node?

I do realize the question is not very well structured, but please understand I am just starting out, and haven’t found any solution by Google searches.
I’m using ros2 foxy and for now, plan to use the lidar standalone with no real purpose, just testing various codes, instead of working with simulations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The package you refer to is written in c++, not in python.

You can't simply mix c++ and python.

You can start a python node, and you can start a c++ node, and they can participate in the same ROS graph (i.e. they can publish and subscribe to each other's topics, or provide services and clients, etc), as long as they are both of the same ROS version and use the same RMW implementation. But if you'd want to import some c++ source code to use that function inside your python node, then the only option is to study the code and rewrite that functionality in python.

If you want to learn c++, I can recommend [learncpp.com](https://www.learncpp.com/).

Then go through the c++ [ROS 2 tutorials](https://docs.ros.org/en/iron/Tutorials.html).

In order to learn how to import python packages in your project, have a look at:

- The [creating a package](https://docs.ros.org/en/iron/Tutorials/Beginner-Client-Libraries/Creating-Your-First-ROS2-Package.html) tutorial,
- The other ROS 2 Python tutorials, e.g. [creating a publisher and subscriber](https://docs.ros.org/en/iron/Tutorials/Beginner-Client-Libraries/Writing-A-Simple-Py-Publisher-And-Subscriber.html#), or [service and client](https://docs.ros.org/en/iron/Tutorials/Beginner-Client-Libraries/Writing-A-Simple-Py-Service-And-Client.html),
- The [python demos](https://github.com/ros2/demos/tree/rolling/demo_nodes_py)
- General other examples, e.g. [this previous ROS Answers question](https://answers.ros.org/question/367793/including-a-python-module-in-a-ros2-package/).

Comment: Generally what would be the usage process for packages that ARE written in python? also, would it be feasable to convert this to be compatible with python since I would prefer to use python for my overall project? I remember seeing that ros2 packages can support both ament_cmake and ament_python build at the same time.

Comment: I have edited my answer. I really think you should start with writing some exercise code, i.e. creating a first package, defining a node with a publisher in it, creating another package with a custom message interface, using that in your first package, etc. This is all described step by step in the tutorials. If you understand how to import the custom message interface package, it will be more straightforward to learn to import other packages.

Comment: Thank you, I have already gone through the tutorials, but decided to skip the custom message one as i thought most of the interfaces are already prebuilt.. it came back to bite very fast. I think for now I will study the code and try to re-write it in python.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to Robotics Stack Exchange!

It is complicated to understand the question as it is not structured well. Based on the description, I feel that you have the following intention. You are trying to ask whether the below practice is followed in ROS:

```
# This is a dummy code
import ld08_driver
driver = ld08_driver()
speed = driver.GetSpeed()
```

*Please assume the above code is written in your package, which differs from the package you mentioned ([ROBOTIS-GIT/ld08_driver](https://github.com/ROBOTIS-GIT/ld08_driver)).*

Now, based on the title *"How do I use other packages while writing my own package"*, the answer (to question whether the abive practice is followed in ROS) is, No. ROS does not use the above practice. Instead, you should do the following:

1. Please invoke the launch file by using the following command:

   ```
   ros2 launch ld08_driver ld08.launch.py
   ```
2. Depending on the package, they may create publishers, subscribers, services, etc. You can easily list out the information by executing ROS commands. However, it is strongly advised to look at the package documentation.
3. In the case of [ROBOTIS-GIT/ld08_driver](https://github.com/ROBOTIS-GIT/ld08_driver), it seems to be creating a publisher of type `sensor_msgs::msg::LaserScan`
4. In your package, you should create a subscriber of `sensor_msgs::msg::LaserScan` type which subscriber to above topic. This is how, you can get the data (laser scan) from the driver in ROS.

Please feel free to read and try [the official ROS 2 documentation](https://docs.ros.org/en/foxy/Tutorials/Beginner-Client-Libraries/Writing-A-Simple-Cpp-Publisher-And-Subscriber.html#write-the-subscriber-node) at any time.